How to Navigate Like WhatsApp, for a Target Screen on Notification Click in Cold State (Terminated) and Warm State Differently in Flutter
In WhatsApp, I noticed two different navigation flows based on the app's state:
Initial Navigation Flow:
Splash Screen → Home Screen
Use Case 1: App is Open or Minimized (Warm State)
A message notification is displayed.
When the user clicks the notification, the app navigates directly to the chat screen from the current screen.
Navigation works as expected, with no issues.
Use Case 2: App is Terminated or Closed (Cold State)
When a message notification is displayed, and the user clicks it, the app:
Directly navigates to the chat screen (skipping the splash and home screens).
When the user presses the back button, it navigates to the home screen, allowing the user to access other parts of the app.
Code
FileName: main.dart
const String defaultAppId = "API-Key";

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await initializeApp();
  runApp(MyTaxiApp());
}

Future<void> initializeApp() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String? currentAppId = prefs.getString("currentAppId") ?? defaultAppId;
  OneSignal.Debug.setLogLevel(OSLogLevel.verbose);
  OneSignal.initialize(currentAppId);
}

class MyTaxiApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String? screen;

    OneSignal.Notifications.addClickListener((listener) {
      final data = listener.notification.additionalData;
      screen = data?['screen'];
      if (screen != null) {
        navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed(screen!);
      }
    });

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Taxi App',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => HomeScreen(),
        '/rideDetails': (context) => RideDetailsScreen(),
        '/rideHistory': (context) => RideHistoryScreen(),
        '/payment': (context) => PaymentScreen(),
        '/profile': (context) => ProfileScreen(),
        '/settings': (context) => SettingsScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}

SplashScreen Code
class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home');
    });

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.yellow.shade300,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Icon(Icons.local_taxi, size: 100, color: Colors.white), // Logo
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Text(
              "Taxi Delivery",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white), // Company Name
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.white), // Loading Indicator
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

OneSignal Notification API Request for Notification
{
  "app_id": "App-ID",
  "target_channel": "push",
  "headings": {"en": "English Title", "es": "Spanish Title"},
  "contents": {"en": "English Message", "es": "Spanish Message"},
  "include_aliases": {
    "external_id": [
      "User_1",
      "USER_ID_2"
    ]
  },
  "data": {"screen": "/payment"}
}

The Problem:
In my implementation, the navigation during the terminated state is causing issues because of the default splash screen logic:
Current Flow in Terminated State:
Splash Screen → Target Screen → Home Screen
(The splash screen logic runs as the app initializes, and after a 3-second delay, it navigates to the home screen. This overrides the target screen navigation, causing an unwanted transition to the home screen.)
Expected Flow in Terminated State:
Target Screen → Home Screen (on back button press)
(The app should directly open the target screen without showing the splash screen. If the back button is pressed, it should navigate to the home screen.)
Requirement:
In the terminated state, skip the splash screen and directly navigate to the target screen when the notification is clicked. Ensure pressing the back button from the target screen navigates to the home screen.
In the warm state (foreground or background), clicking the notification should navigate directly to the target screen without affecting the existing app flow.
Current Setup:
I am using OneSignal for handling notification clicks. The navigation to the target screen is triggered when a notification is clicked. However, the splash screen logic interferes during the terminated state due to its 3-second delay and automatic navigation to the home screen.
Question:
How can I implement the expected navigation behavior by correctly applying flags or modifying the logic to achieve the desired navigation flow?
